# automatically update model to reflect new schema changes cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table in a CakePHP 2 application. I added a field to my table, but on the baked page for that model, I don't see any HTML element to save the data in the newly added field in my model.

Is there a shell command or something that I can run to make CakePHP aware of that new change to my database table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem to add code manually ? New change will no come automatically without you add it by yourself manually or bake.

Answer (score 0):

Delete app/tmp/cache/models files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10163621)

Comment: ok. will do it in the future. however i do think that it is an answer to the question.

Comment: I do think this counts as an answer. It would be prefered to add some explanation why this will solve the problem but it still is an answer.